# Can I Use Two Colons in This Sentence?

Tags: sentence, colons

> Conversely, the substitution effect moves in the opposite direction: as the price of breakfast cereal rises, so does its opportunity cost: other goods become relatively cheaper and thus more attractive.

The practice of using two colons in a single sentence is often discouraged, but it seems to me to make sense in the sentence above.

So is this an acceptable use of colons, or should use an alternative form of punctuation. If so, what?

Comment: Wouldn't periods work as well?

Comment: I would recommend a semicolon between "cost" and "other."

Comment: Or replace the first colon with a period, and the second colon with something like *at the same time that*. While the use of two colons is not objectively wrong, it's not very easy to parse without some rephrasing.